# Why doesn't this short comparison optimize the way I expected?

Tags: c++, assembly, optimization

I have a compound index type that consists of two 16-bit integers packed together into a 32-bit object designed to be passed around and treated a bit like a pointer. But I chanced to notice that the comparison operators I defined weren't being optimized the way I expected.

Given this cut-down code:

```cxx
#include <cstdint>

struct TwoParter {
    std::uint16_t blk;
    std::uint16_t ofs;
};
static_assert (sizeof(TwoParter) == sizeof(std::uint32_t), "pack densely");

bool equal1 (TwoParter const & lhs, TwoParter const & rhs) {
    return lhs.blk == rhs.blk && lhs.ofs == rhs.ofs;
}

bool equal2 (TwoParter const & lhs, TwoParter const & rhs) {
    auto lp = reinterpret_cast <std::uint32_t const *> (&lhs);
    auto rp = reinterpret_cast <std::uint32_t const *> (&rhs);
    return *lp == *rp;
}
```

GCC (7.1 on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/)) produces the following assembly (options `-m64 -std=c++11 -O3`):

```
equal1(TwoParter const&, TwoParter const&):
        movzwl  (%rsi), %edx
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        cmpw    %dx, (%rdi)
        je      .L5
        rep ret
.L5:
        movzwl  2(%rsi), %eax
        cmpw    %ax, 2(%rdi)
        sete    %al
        ret
equal2(TwoParter const&, TwoParter const&):
        movl    (%rsi), %eax
        cmpl    %eax, (%rdi)
        sete    %al
        ret
```

One of these seems to be doing more work than the other. But I just can't see how they're different: the assertion guarantees that the layout of the struct is such that the comparison as a `uint23_t` *must* compare all of the same data as examining the `uint16_t` fields separately. More importantly, this is x86, so the compiler already knew that would be the case. The short-circuiting behaviour of `&&` shouldn't be important to the output, because its right-hand operand has no effects (and the compiler can see this), and since nothing else interesting is happening I can't imagine why it would want to e.g. defer loading the second half of the data.

Replacing the `&&` with the `&` operator gets rid of the jump but does not fundamentally change what the code does: it still generates two separate 16-bit comparisons, instead of comparing all of the data in one go, which indicates that the short-circuit is probably not the issue (although it does raise a related question of why it doesn't compile `&&` and `&` the same way either - surely one of the two should be "better" in both cases).

What interests me is that, also according to Compiler Explorer, all the major compilers (GCC, Clang, Intel, MSVC) seem to do roughly the same thing. That reduces the chances that this is an oversight on the part of one optimizer, but what I can't see is how my own assessment of this is actually wrong.

So there are two parts to this:

1) does `equal1` really do the same thing as `equal2`? Am I missing something crazy here?

2) if it does, why would compilers choose not to emit the shorter instruction sequence?

I'm sure that optimizations *in this vein* must be something compilers know about, because they would be more legitimately useful for speeding up other, more serious code like e.g. `memcmp` shoving things into vector registers to compare more data at once.

Comment: Maybe due to the requirement to short-circuit the `&&` operator?

Comment: @MarkRansom this is probably what "Replacing the `&&` with the `&` operator" is about.

Comment: The version with the `&&` operator can be easily explained with introducing a read that could cause a race condition, but I'm clueless for `&`.

Comment: I can't see how short-circuiting has any effect here - the compiler can plainly see that the expression on the right is side-effect free. More importantly, as I mentioned in the question, the non-short-circuitiing `&` operator generates very similar code.

Comment: Possible problems which might forbids optimization I can see: alignment restriction, and endianness.

Comment: @Jarod42 endianness? That shouldn't hinder bitwise comparison, should it?

Comment: @Jarod42 good catch, adding `alignas (std::uint32_t)` to the declaration of TwoParter makes them identical. Want to turn that into an answer? I thought ints had no alignment requirement on x86?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alignment requirement are not the same, `TwoParter` has same alignment than `std::uint16_t`.

Changing `TwoParter` to

```
struct alignas(std::uint32_t) TwoParter {
    std::uint16_t blk;
    std::uint16_t ofs;
};
```

produces same asm for gcc 7.1:

```
equal1(TwoParter const&, TwoParter const&):
        movl    (%rsi), %eax
        cmpl    %eax, (%rdi)
        sete    %al
        ret
equal2(TwoParter const&, TwoParter const&):
        movl    (%rsi), %eax
        cmpl    %eax, (%rdi)
        sete    %al
        ret
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/2jImSx)

Comment: Why does alignment, which isn't really a thing on x86, scare the compiler anyway?

Comment: @harold, doesn't misalignment cause a potential slowdown even on (some) x86 processor?

Comment: Although my understanding of it was that the original code *should* work equally well on x86 either way, it's probably better to be defensive about it. Perhaps it isn't worth the optimizer's time to consider whether the maybe-slower access is still better than the separate, correct, accesses?

Comment: @zch well, yes on Core2 if you accidentally cross a cache line boundary.. but that's ancient history

Comment: @zch even if it would, it was usually around +1 clock (unless you had real cache miss), so I would still expect the two-part 16b code to be lot slower, even for unaligned reads. Maybe it's just not well covered by optimizer, as anyone paying so much attention to performance of this case is expected to guard also alignment?